# Cannot select from 1 to many tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use Entity Framework 6.1 in C# to get all rows from two tables. Here's an excerpt from my model:
[image]
The aim is to populate a `List<Task>` from a SQL Server database. `Task` is autogenerated:

```
public partial class Task
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Task()
    {
        this.Rotas = new HashSet<Rota>();
        this.PeopleOnTasks = new HashSet<PeopleOnTask>();
        this.TaskRotaSaves = new HashSet<TaskRotaSave>();
    }

public int TaskID { get; set; }
public string TaskName { get; set; }
public string Frequency { get; set; }
public string RotaResultsPath { get; set; }
public bool Active { get; set; }

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<Rota> Rotas { get; set; }
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<PeopleOnTask> PeopleOnTasks { get; set; }
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<TaskRotaSave> TaskRotaSaves { get; set; }
```

}

I have tried many things. The nearest attempt is:

```
var t2 = dbContext.Tasks.Include("PeopleOnTasks");
```

which apparently generates the correct SQL. When I run the SQL in SSMS, I see that that each task has at least 3 PeopleOnTask records; but in the application, I only every get one. I have tried to iterate the PeopleOnTask collection, to eliminate any lazy loading confusion.

This query gets the correct data (plus some other stuff), but it is not in a format I can use.

```
var rawData = dbContext.PeopleOnTasks.Include("Task");
```

This SQL does the job exactly. My last resort is to use it in a stored procedure.

```
SELECT t.TaskID, t.TaskName, t.Frequency, t.RotaResultsPath, t.Active, p1.PersonID, p1.PersonName, 
tm.TeamID, te.TeamName, p2.PersonID AS TeamPersonID, 
p2.PersonName AS TeamPersonName, pt.CopyOnly,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM Note N
                    WHERE N.ForeignKey = pt.TaskID and N.ForeignTable = 'Task')
        THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
END AS HasNote

FROM PeopleOnTask AS pt 
INNER JOIN Task AS t ON t.TaskID = pt.TaskID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person AS p1 ON pt.PeopleID = p1.PersonID and pt.PeopleType = 'p'
LEFT OUTER JOIN TeamMember AS tm ON pt.PeopleID = tm.TeamID and pt.PeopleType = 't'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Team AS te ON te.TeamID = tm.TeamID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person AS p2 ON tm.PersonID = p2.PersonID 
ORDER BY t.TaskName
```

Is it possible to fix the first attempt, or do I need to write loads of code to reformat the second attempt?

I am not worried about the Note and other links at this stage, just getting the correct PeopleOnTask records returned.

Thanks.

**Edit, after Ben Jones answer**

This attempt also fails. An exception is thrown "The entity or complex type 'NameSpace.Task' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.", with  HResult = -2146233067.

```
    var t2 = dbContext.PeopleOnTasks.Include("Task").Select(x => new Task
    {
        TaskID = x.TaskID,
        TaskName = x.Task.TaskName,
        Active = x.Task.Active,
        Frequency = x.Task.Frequency,
        RotaResultsPath = x.Task.RotaResultsPath,
        PeopleOnTasks = x.Task.PeopleOnTasks,
        TaskRotaSaves = x.Task.TaskRotaSaves
    });
```

Comment: Can you not alter the format into a format which you prefer? When you select data from a database that often happens

Answer (score 0):

If this one works

```
var rawData = dbContext.PeopleOnTasks.Include("Task");
```

why not then parse this into the object you want using

```
var rawData = dbContext.PeopleOnTasks.Include("Task").Select(x => new insertclass {
 property = x.prop
});
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by `insertclass`. Please see my edit.